# how to get current position when clicked a button in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the first time I try with google maps. I just want to create a simple application. There is a button. Whenever I clicked to the button, the current position (also the current latitude and longitude) is displayed to a TextView. To do that, do I have to add some libraries or not, which permission do I have to add to the AndroidManifest? Could anybody give me a guide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access GPS to get current position of device, and you would need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in manifest file. follow the link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html.

Answer (score 0):

Add the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

also along with the permissions mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

See the below link. it will provide both latitude, longitude and current location address.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/02/get-locationlatitude-and-longitude-from.html